# MDX Sum Function

Tags: sum, mdx

We have this data...

Date          PhonesSold 
1/1/2011 - 1 
1/2/2011 - 3 
1/3/2011 - 2 
1/4/2011 - 4

Is it possible to create an MDX query that results in the following results?

Date          TotalPhonesSold 
1/1/2011 - 1 
1/2/2011 - 4 
1/3/2011 - 6 
1/4/2011 - 10

I'm guessing I'll use the SUM function. It has this syntax.

Sum( Set_Expression [ , Numeric_Expression ] )

Now, how do I specify the set?

Comment: What's the granularity of your time dimension? If the lowest level is Day, PhonesSold should automatically give you the total value by day. Or, are the Date values in your example wrong, and each row refers to a different day (1/1/2011 1/2/2011, etc)?

Comment: Whoah. It is wrong. Editing now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want a running total?

[Speed up Running Total MDX calculated measure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018080/speed-up-running-total-mdx-calculated-measure)

http://www.sqldev.org/sql-server-analysis-services/mdx-running-total-calculated-member-18945.shtml

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlanalysisservices/thread/100521f2-8533-4fd1-9071-96dc5373572c

This looks like a good one for performance:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlanalysisservices/thread/fcd061a7-e941-4c4a-9945-59e1b48c422e